# why print(mylist.append(5)) prints None

Tags: python, list

```
lst = [2,3,4]
print(lst.append(1))
```

why the above print is returning None

while `print(lst[1])` works?

Comment: because the `append` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: `list.append()` is a method and returns `None` and `list[1]` returns the second element of the list.

Comment: More precisely, `append` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`lst.append` always returns None, and that's what `print` prints.

To append and print the last element:

```
lst = [2,3,4]
lst.append("foo")
print(lst[-1])  # Prints foo
```

Answer (score -1):

yes that is because the function (`list.append`) returns noting. If you print the result it prints thus `None`.

```py
def f1(x):
    print(x)
    return None

def f2(x):
    print(x)
    return x

print(f1(2))
>>> 2  # inside the function
>>> None  # return value of function
print(f2(2))
>>> 2  # inside the function
>>> 2  # return value of function
```